# Location of tests file in an R package

Tags: r, r-package, testthat, covr

If I have **tests/testhat/testhat.R**, `devtools::test()` finds it and runs it, but `covr:package_coverage()` and `R CMD check` does not find it.

If I have it as **tests/testhat.R**, `devtools::test()` doesn't find it but `covr:package_coverage()` and `R CMD check` does.

What's the best way to do this?

*R 4.0.0; testthat 2.3.2; covr 3.5.0*

Comment: You can specify a path as the first argument to `devtools::test()`. Without testing it, my guess is use the second directory structure. Besides, from the manual: *`test()` is a shortcut for `testthat::test_dir()`*.

Comment: Have you tried using `tests` instead of `test`? That's the directory I get automatically when adding tests via `usethis::use_test` or `usethis::use_testthat`.

Comment: Ah sorry! I am using `tests` folder as the parent. I mistyped here. Correcting it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your directory structure of the `test` folder should look like this:

```
.
├── testthat
│   ├── test-1.R
│   ├── test-2.R
│   ├── test-3.R
│   ├── test-4.R
│   └── test-5.R
└── testthat.R
```

And `testthat.R` contains

```
library(testthat)
library(mypackage)

test_check("mypackage")
```

This works with `R CMD check`, `covr` and `devtools::check()`.

Comment: How does this help? All the tests inside testthat folder do not run during R CMD check or for code coverage.

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with the  tests? The structure is that one. See http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/tests.html for more or see how it's done here: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/tree/master/tests/testthat

Comment: Ah! I see. In the example you linked, `testthat.R` has this code `test_check("ggplot2")` which I suppose runs all the individual tests inside the `testthat` folder.